# Why isn't my procedure in MySQL working

Tags: php, mysql, procedure

So I have this procedure written in MySQL, can anyone tell me why it isn't working?

```
create procedure add_Order(
    IN custid int,
    IN productid int,
    IN storeid int,
    IN  empid int,
    IN quantity int,
    IN R_payment char(10),
    IN date date)
begin
    insert into Orders(custid, empid, storeid, orderdate) values (IN_cust, IN_empid, IN_storeid, IN_date);
    insert into Order_Product(orderid, productid, quantity, RegisterPayment) values (IN_orderid, IN_productid, IN_quantity, IN_R_payment);
end
```

This is the error message:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'end' at line 1
```

Comment: You need to define a different delimiter to use. See mysql manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html

Comment: The values field names need to math the in parameter names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `add_Order`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `add_Order`(
    IN custid int,
    IN productid int,
    IN storeid int,
    IN  empid int,
    IN quantity int,
    IN R_payment char(10),IN date date
)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Orders(custid, empid, storeid, orderdate) values (IN_cust,IN_empid, IN_storeid, IN_date);
    INSERT INTO Order_Product(orderid, productid, quantity, RegisterPayment) values (IN_orderid, IN_productid, IN_quantity, IN_R_payment);
END
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

**Reference:** 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html

**You can also use this tool:**
http://tools.knowledgewalls.com/mysqlcreateprocedure

Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

use DELIMITER //

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `add_Order` $$
    create procedure add_Order(IN custid int, IN productid int, IN storeid int, IN 
    empid int, IN quantity int,
    IN R_payment char(10), IN date date)
    begin
    insert into Orders(custid, empid, storeid, orderdate) values (IN_cust, 
    IN_empid, IN_storeid, IN_date);
    insert into Order_Product(orderid, productid, quantity, RegisterPayment) 
    values (IN_orderid, IN_productid, IN_quantity, IN_R_payment);
    end $$
DELIMITER ;
```